# Pinescript backtesting low timeframes

Tags: bitcoin, pine-script

What defines the numbers of bars that allow backtesting? 1m chart shows approx. 1 week -> too little to do any meaningful backtesting between 1m, 5m or 1h chart -> I would like to backtest these e.g. one month and already know how to limit the backtest time, the real problem is there only seems to be x number of bars back -> HOW DO I GET 1m BARS FURTHER IN TIME?

Because of this and many other limitation (I had to convert strategy -> study) I am considering coding my own bot in Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The number of bars is determined by your type of account (Premium accounts get a theoretical minimum of 10K bars), but the exact number you get will also be dependent on the ticker/TF. You may get only one bar on a 12M chart for a recent ticker, and up to 25K bars on other ticher/TF combos.